# Questions about HTML parsing

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, html-parsing, global-variables

This is a program we've written for html parsing.
It works perfectly.

We found a demo program on the net, and we modified it for our needs.
But we don't understand how it works.

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen


address='http://www.iitb.ac.in/acadpublic/RunningCourses.jsp?deptcd=EE&year=2012&semester=1'
print(address)
source= urlopen(address).read()
source=str(source)


from html.parser import HTMLParser

str1 = input('Enter name of prof:')

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    y=" "
    def handle_data(self, data):
        flag=0
        x=str(data)
        for i in range(len(x)):
            if (x[i]=='\\'):
                flag=1
                break
        if(flag==0) :
            if(x==str1):
                global y
                print("Name of professor:",x)
                print("Name of course:",y) 
            y=x

parser = MyHTMLParser(strict=False)
parser.feed(source)
```

Our questions:

1. why does the class `HTMLparser` have to be called in the first place?
2. why is that function `handle_data` being called, and how does that function work?
3. why is `global y` necessary despite `y` being in the class itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is not being called; you are inheriting from it instead; `MyHTMLParser` is called to create an instance of the class.
2. `handle_data()` is called by the `HTMLParser` code; your subclass overrides it to handle textual data in the document. By calling `.feed()` on your `MyHTMLParser` instance the process is started.

   See the [`html.parser` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) documentation for the full API. You could try to understand the [full `html.parser` source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/html/parser.py) if you really want to know how this all works.
3. The example you found is doing things quite wrong, actually. The `global y` refers to a **different** `y` variable, one that lives in the module scope. That line shows that the original developer of that example did not understand what they were doing. The `global y` line is not the only example; the code could be made much more Pythonic in other ways.

   The `y` definition in the class scope otherwise unused. The `handle_data()` method should refer to `self.y` instead:

   ```
   class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
       y = None

       def handle_data(self, data):
           if '\\' not in data:
               if data == str1:
                   print("Name of professor:", data)
                   print("Name of course:", self.y) 
               self.y = x
   ```

   This stores the element text in `self.y` for each element, and if a *next* element matches your `str1` global variable, then it is printed as well, together with the professor name.

You may want to look into using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead for a more intuitive HTML parser API.